# How to replace an Embedding layer with a Time Distributed Dense after training?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, neural-network, embedding, keras

I have the following problem:

1. I want to use a LSTM network for text classification. In order to speed up training and make code more clear I want to use an `Embedding` layer along `keras.Tokenizer` in order to train my model.
2. Once I trained my model - I want to compute a saliency map of output w.r.t. the input. To do that I decided to replace an `Embedding` layer with a `TimeDistributedDense`.

Do you have any idea what is the best way to do that. For a simple model I'm able to simply rebuild model with a known weights - but I want to make it as generic as possible - e.g. to replace the model structure the future and make my framework as model agnostic as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new model with the existing layers after training without losing the trained information. Creating models does not overwrite values, it just rearranges the flow of tensors. For example, if your model looks like this:

```
# Create model for training, includes Embedding layer
in = Input(...)
em = Embedding(...)
l1 = LSTM(...)
l2 = TimeDistributed(Dense(...))

t_em = em(in)
t_l1 = l1(t_em)
t_l2 = l2(t_l1)

model_train = Model(inputs=[in], outputs=[t_l2])
model_train.compile(...)
model_train.fit(...)

# Create model for salience map, ignores Embedding layer
t_l1 = l1(in)
t_l2 = l2(in)
model_saliency = Model(inputs=[in], outputs=[t_l2])
```

As a side note, `TimeDistributedDense` is deprecated, use `wrappers.TimeDistributed`.

Comment: But how would you impose the embedding output and input shape to be the same? These are completely different?

Comment: You can always extract the important section of your model into a model of its own and supply it an `Embedding` input if it needs one. Models can be used as normal layers/tensors can be.